# Tweepy - get expanded url using paginator (elevated access level)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm collecting full urls from tweets (not t.co ones), for that I needed to use option `tweet_mode="extended"` which you get in elevated access level (that I have).

I want to get full urls using Paginator.
I don't know how to do this except collecting tweet ids first and then calling `api.get_status` like this:

```
for sq in search_q: 
  for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets,sq).flatten(limit=5):
    tweet_ids.append(tweet.id)
    
for tid in tweet_ids:
    status = api.get_status(tid, tweet_mode="extended")
    full_urls.append(status.entities['urls'][0]['expanded_url'])
```

which seems awfully inefficient.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a tweet_fields for entities solves this.

```
for sq in search_q: 
  for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets,sq,tweet_fields=["entities"]).flatten(limit=5):
    tweet_ids.append(tweet.data["entities"]['urls'][0]['expanded_url'])
```